# How to permanently change behavior of markers for app?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I want to make it so that when a user creates a marker in google maps, it is able to be double clicked (or held on or something) and bring up a new Activity. Right now I have it so that I create a marker on the map manually and use an `onMarkerClickListener` to wait until the marker is clicked to launch the new activity. Basically, I want to make it so that all markers created inside my app share this behavior, and I need some sort of check to differentiate between my own user marker and Google/external Markers.

Here is the code below:

```
public void setUsermarker() {

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.equals(userMarker)) {  //if clicked marker equals marker created by user
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ObjectViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }       //Otherwise just show the info window
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You could just remove the condition `if (marker.equals(userMarker))` and then the ObjectViewActivity Activity would be launched from clicking on any Marker.

Comment: I thought about this, but wouldn't external markers be affected too? E.g. ones placed by google that are on the map by default. Can't exactly check right now though because my maps aren't reloading the tiles when I zoom out...

Comment: After fixing my maps (API key randomly changed) I tried out what you said. It works for my "userMarkers" but the regular Google markers (for the US capitol, for example) aren't registered in maps. So I need some sort of check to differentiate between my own user marker and Google/external markers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the ID of each Marker that you explicitly add to your map in a `Set<String>` in order to differentiate them from the other Markers on your map.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#getId()

```
    //instance variables:
    LatLng latLng;
    String title;
    String snippet;
    Set<String> markerIDs = new HashSet<String>();
```

When adding a Marker in your app, capture the returned Marker, get the ID,  and add the ID to the Set:

```
    //Adding your markers
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet));

    //Add each ID to the Set
    String id = marker.getId();
    markerIDs.add(id);
```

Then, just check if the Marker ID is in the Set before launching the other Activity:

```
public void setUsermarker() {

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (markerIDs.contains(marker.getId())) {  //if clicked marker equals marker created by user
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ObjectViewActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }       //Otherwise just show the info window
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, that helped me, thank you! One thing about the code, Set<String> markerIDs = new Set<String>();  has to be changed to        new HashSet<String>();   (or some other type of set, I just chose a HashSet) since you cant instantiate the type Set since it is an interface. Also, in my case, if someone were to use this code they should just make sure they are creating a marker to .getId from, as MarkerOptions doesn't have that method. Thanks again!

Comment: @retromode you read my mind! I just realized that and was about to make that change to HashSet. Glad it works for you!